# postgresSql delete middle table but replace chained relation with single relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables. Table 1, Table 2, Table 3.

Table 2 has a table1Id relation, Table 3 has a table2Id relation.

I wan to delete table 2, but I want to maintain the chained relation between Table 3 and Table 1. So to say, move Table 2's relation to Table 1 to new column in Table 3, then remove relation between table 3 and 2, and finally delete table 2.

**Something like this:**

```
alter table "db"."Table 3" add column "table1Id" bigint not noll references "db"."Table 1"("id") on delete cascade;
-- update new field to point to the tbale1Id where table 2 previously pointed to
alter table "db"."Table 3" drop column "table2Id";
drop table "db"."Table 2";
```

Data before:

> Table 1: (id: 337), (id: 7)
>
> Table 2: (id: 214, table1Id: 337), (id: 16, table1Id: 7)
>
> Table 3: (id: 9, table2Id: 214), (id: 998, table2Id: 16)

Wanted data after migration:

> Table 1: (id: 337), (id: 7)
>
> Table 3: (id: 9, table1Id: 337), (id: 998, table1Id: 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following migration script:

```
-- add the new column
alter table table3 add column table1_id bigint references table1(id) on delete cascade;

-- initialize the content
update table3 t3 set table1_id = (
    select table1_id from table2 t2 where t2.id = t3.table2_id
);

-- make the column not nullable
alter table table3 alter column table1_id set not null;

-- cleanup
alter table table3 drop column table2_id;
drop table table2_id;
```

Notes: since the table already contains records, you cannot create the column as `not null`; you need to populate it first, then apply the `not null` constraint.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=19f33f50d4ad6b5b68807919b334dc48)**:

Content of `table3` after running the script:

```
 id | table1_id
--: | --------:
  9 |       337
998 |         7
```

Comment: Oh, right. the not null constraint can only be made after update. I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: And there is no need for a where clause on the update statement? So it will update all records of table 3?

Comment: @RasmusPuls: the update statement uses a correlated subquery to locate the relevant record in `table2`: `where t2.id = t3.table2_id`. This will update all records in `table3` with the `table1_id` of the relevant record from `table2`.